# Where to store credentials used in a function?

Tags: functions, password, authentication

I am writing a function in `functions.php` under my theme. The function contains a cURL command that uses credentials like "account_id" and "password". These credentials are not from user input.

Where can I store these credentials? And how would I retrieve them to use them in my function?

Answer (score 1):

You could store it as `variables`

```
$account_id = 'your_account_id';
$password = 'your password';
someFunction($account_id, $password);
```

Or store it in `{$table_prefix}_options` table and retrieve it by `get_option` function

```
$account_id = get_option('account_id');
$password = get_option('password');
someFunction($account_id, $password);
```

You could save this values, for example from admin panel, by `update_option` function.

Second option is better, because you can share your `functions.php` with others and they will not know your credentials. It is also important, that password shouldn't be stored as plain text.

- [get_option function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/)
- [update_option function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)